# iPad Font Size Increase for iPhone App

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uifont

My iPhone app looks great in 2x mode on the iPad. The only thing that doesn't is the text. This is the code I'm using to define the font size for certain variables:

```
[letter setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:30]];
```

Since I use several different font sizes throughout the app, is there a simple statement that can go with this to say, if on iPad, size:50? Thanks!

Comment: A much better solution is to build universal application with two different user interfaces, for iPhone and iPad. In this application you can detect if it's iPad or iPhone using `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` macro or `[UIDevice userInterfaceIdiom]` method.

Comment: I second the above. A purely scaled up iPhone app is almost never appropriate, apart from for games.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like others have mentioned, it's generally better to have two separate interfaces- but if your particular app still functions well when scaled up, than this should solve your problem:

Use:

```
#define IS_PAD  (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
```

To determine if the app is being run on an iPad. Then, you can use a ternary operator to choose the proper font size:

```
[letter setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:IS_PAD?50:30]];
```

That will give you a font size of 50 on the iPad and 30 for everything else.

Comment: Thanks, great answer! Where should I put this initial line, a specific file or just along with the letter string: #define IS_PAD  UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone

Comment: Near the top of your source file (say, just below your "@implementation" line) should do nicely :)

Comment: I tried this on an app that is iPhone only and ran it on iPad and it will always return as if it is iPhone, because when it is built it is being built for iPhone so the iPad runs a container which is just an iPhone window. So the iPhone window size on the iPad will be the same for if it was a normal iPhone. So you can't use this macro to determine if it is iPhone or iPad. So I do believe this is incorrect.

Comment: @Popeye, that's a very different scenario- this solution is designed to find the interface being used, rather than the device, as that is what the O.P. was looking for. Since the app you're testing with is designed only for the iPhone, it will always be using the iPhone interface. If you need to find the actual device being used, the `UIDevice` class (particularly `[[UIDevice currentDevice] model]`) is probably what you're looking for- but again, that's a very different scenario!

Comment: Despite high precedence of `==` operator, I think the macro should still be wrapped in parentheses.

Comment: @tia — one year after you asked, I'm complying with that request.